# performance of dom element vs jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

which one is faster

```
document.getElementsByName('tempName')[0].value
```

or

```
$('[name="tempName"]')[0].value
```

I want to know because I'm writing js codes were I have to use it for around 10 thousand times  on every change of a single field and I want to know its effect on performance.

Comment: find out yourself: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: The problem is that they aren't equivalent, you can't meaningfully compare them. jQuery's purpose is to *normalize* your interaction with the DOM across all browsers. Under the hood, jQuery is doing more than simply giving you your element. You'd have to modify your non-jQuery example to work for browsers that don't even support `getElementsByName` for the two examples to be remotely comparable.

Comment: BTW, in your jQuery example, why not simply `$('[name="tempName"]').val()`?

Comment: @meagar in this case `getElementsByName` is supported even in quite old versions such as IE 5.5: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 4):

The first one seems to be faster. Using pure javascript.

Tested with jsperf: http://jsperf.com/performance-fsdfsd
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript should work faster here. So this one is

```
document.getElementsByName('tempName')[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one. No doubt about it. Not a single test needed for that.

---

However, the questions you should be asking yourself is:

- By how much?
- Does it really matter?
- How big is your app that you worry about these things?
- Is it worth sacrificing readability & cross-browser support for such a tiny gain?

If you can make do without jQuery as a dependency, then you can save yourself & your users some precious bytes. But, if you anyhow need jQuery elsewhere on the page, I don't think fiddling like this is gonna make a real-life difference.

---

**Bottom line**: you should test your real-world example, not just this one abstract line. The vanilla JavaScript might be faster, but if it makes no difference *to your app*, then why bother?

Comment: and which one offers better support, given. `getElementsByName` is a poorer example of what I mean but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: And **what gains do I get in return for the small performance loss?**

Comment: Here's a jsperf for ya: http://jsperf.com/by-name-test -- tl;dr pure JS was faster by 97% in Chrome for me

Comment: It is pretty big. Consider this, about 50 forms wrapped up in a single HTML document and each form has around 40 to 50 numeric fields... with hectic calculations in between.